# Paypal Sandbox integration for android

Tags: android, paypal

I use paypal integration using android paypal sdk, and i use this code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     Intent intent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);


        startService(intent);

        }

 public void onBuyPressed(View pressed) {
     PayPalPayment thingToBuy = getThingToBuy(PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PaymentActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);

}
```

I got error like this request failed with server response:

```
{"name":"TRANSACTION_REFUSED","message":"The request was refused.{0}","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#TRANSACTION_REFUSED","debug_id":"f1123aecd0ece"}
05-15 13:36:53.530: E/PayPalService(9581): TRANSACTION_REFUSED
```

anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

```
public class PaymentConfermationFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX;
private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "ASdSlRC8iBoCu6ehg59npQXZfhfhfhfhfhl6xQVx0IcYKCCUrZNfcdTBI0zdYCroY1ONz";
private static final String CONFIG_RECEIVER_EMAIL = "xyz@gmail.com";

private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
private TextView frind_name, amount;
private ImageView frind_img;

private GiftekFriend giftekFriend;
private ArrayList<GiftekProduct> productList;

private View mLoadingCover;
private View mPaymentOK;

long price = 0;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_payment_confirmation, container, false);

    frind_img = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.friend_img);
    frind_name = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.friend_name);

    mLoadingCover = rootView.findViewById(R.id.loading_cover);
    mPaymentOK = rootView.findViewById(R.id.payment_ok);

    amount = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.amount);

    ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Payment");

    giftekFriend = AppData.getInstance().getGiftekFriend();
    if (giftekFriend != null) {
        String name = giftekFriend.first_name + " " + giftekFriend.last_name;
        frind_name.setText(name);
    }

    productList = AppData.getInstance().getProductList();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), PayPalService.class);

    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT, CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID, CONFIG_CLIENT_ID);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RECEIVER_EMAIL, CONFIG_RECEIVER_EMAIL);
    getActivity().startService(intent);

    rootView.findViewById(R.id.payment_button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            paymentStart();
        }
    });
    new Imageloder().execute();
    mFragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

    return rootView;
}

protected void paymentStart() {

    PayPalPayment thingToBuy = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(Integer.parseInt(amount.getText().toString())), "USD", "Giftek Gifts");

    Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), PaymentActivity.class);

    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYPAL_ENVIRONMENT, CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID, CONFIG_CLIENT_ID);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RECEIVER_EMAIL, CONFIG_RECEIVER_EMAIL);

    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_CLIENT_ID, "credential-from-developer.paypal.com");
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYER_ID, "your-customer-id-in-your-system");
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);

    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        PaymentConfirmation confirm = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);

        onPaymentSuccess();
        if (confirm != null) {
            try {
                System.out.print(confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));
                Log.i("paymentExample", confirm.toJSONObject().toString(3));
                Log.i("paymentExample", confirm.toJSONObject().toString(2));
                Log.i("paymentExample", confirm.toJSONObject().toString(1));
                Log.i("paymentExample", confirm.toJSONObject().toString(0));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("paymentExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e);
            }
        }
    } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        onPaymentCancel();
        Log.i("paymentExample", "The user canceled.");
    } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_PAYMENT_INVALID) {
        onPaymentInvalid();
        Log.i("paymentExample", "An invalid payment was submitted. Please see the docs.");
    }
}

private void onPaymentInvalid() {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("result", "Payment Invalid");

    mFragmentManager.popBackStack("giftek-process-select-friend", 0);
    mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, ResultFragment.instantiate(getActivity(), ResultFragment.class.getName(), args))
            .addToBackStack("result").commit();
}

private void onPaymentCancel() {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("result", "Payment Cancel");

    mFragmentManager.popBackStack("giftek-process-select-friend", 0);
    mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, ResultFragment.instantiate(getActivity(), ResultFragment.class.getName(), args))
            .addToBackStack("result").commit();
}

private void onPaymentSuccess() {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("result", "Order has been completed successfully.");

    mFragmentManager.popBackStack("giftek-process-select-friend", 0);
    mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, ResultFragment.instantiate(getActivity(), ResultFragment.class.getName(), args))
            .addToBackStack("result").commit();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    getActivity().stopService(new Intent(getActivity(), PayPalService.class));
    super.onDestroy();
}
```